# Using a single license, how many computers can you install Lightroom 3 on?

Tags: software, lightroom-3

I'm liking the extra editing abilities that Lightroom brings (over picasa), but I'm wondering if I shell out $300 can I use it on as many computers as I like? I know windows generally only allows you to use one key at a time - would Lightroom 3 have a similar restriction? I have a main desktop and a laptop and would like to have it on both if possible.

Comment: Good question. Was planning to ask something similar, but you beat me to it!

Comment: With the price you pay for this software a user should be able to download it to as many computers as they wish.

Comment: It's actually relatively cheap, as commercial software goes. It's also well-designed, innovate software with a lot of (ongoing) research and development. That takes money. If you're on a budget, you may want to try open source alternatives; these are free, but since they're developed without that budget tend to have quirks and shortcomings.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Adobe Lightroom's single license covers installing it on both your main desktop and your laptop. It even allows you to install one copy on a windows computer, and a 2nd copy on a mac.

> How many computers are covered by a single license of Adobe Photoshop Lightroom 3?
>
> Subject to the terms of the software license agreement, the primary user of the computer on which Adobe Photoshop Lightroom 3 is installed may install a second copy of the software for his or her exclusive use on either a portable computer or a computer located at his or her home, provided that the software on the second computer is not used at the same time as the software on the primary computer. Lightroom is sold as multiplatform software, which means it can be installed on either Mac OS X or Windows.

From [Lightroom's FAQ](http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshoplightroom/faq/) under "Pricing and Availability."

Comment: Do you know whether the above also applies to education versions? I'm looking to pick up a student version in the next month, and would like to run it on a desktop and laptop.

Comment: Although I'm not 100% certain, I believe that also applies to education licenses; your best bet is to contact adobe.